# Bash, find and delete old files

Tags: bash, scripting, backup

Write script to backup files and delete old backups:

```
#!/bin/sh

BACKUPDIR=/var/backups/files
ROTATE=1

mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR

CURRENT="$BACKUPDIR/`date +%Y-%m-%d`-files.tar.gz"

cd /var/ && tar czf $CURRENT www

find $BACKUPDIR -type f -mtime $ROTATE -exec rm {} \;

chmod 0600 $BACKUPDIR/*
```

Command Line (for testing):

```
find $BACKUPDIR -type f -mtime $ROTATE -exec rm {} \;
```

Somehow, the script does not work. However, if I execute it in the console, all is OK and old files get deleted. But if I run the script, files are not deleted (tar archive get created when I run the script). Why?

Script permissions are `755`.

Comment: If you want to delete files more than 24hrs old, you should specify `-mtime +0` for find.  `-mtime 1` means files 24hrs to 48hrs old.

Comment: `-mtime 1` mean **exactly** 1 day old from now, so may be there are not such files in your `$BACKUPDIR`

Comment: rather than `-exec rm {}`, you might want to use the `-delete` option.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Fiximan, you probably want to use the `-delete` option, although that should make no difference in your situation, <s>if you were to hit a filename with spaces or other special characters, your script would fail</s>.

```
#!/bin/sh -e

BACKUPDIR=/var/backups/files

# I suggest a little more than 1 day (i.e. about 1 week of backups is
# probably safer.)
ROTATE=7

mkdir -p $BACKUPDIR

CURRENT="$BACKUPDIR/`date +%Y-%m-%d`-files.tar.gz"

# Create protected file, then backup data in it
touch $CURRENT
chmod 600 $CURRENT
cd /var/ && tar czf $CURRENT www

# Here we have the attempt at deleting, notice the "+"
find $BACKUPDIR -type f -name '*-files.tar.gz' -mtime +$ROTATE -delete
```

A few things:

1. `ROTATE=1` does not seem to make much sense, you probably want more than 1 backup, just in case. You often notice something's wrong a few days in... good luck if you have a backup from last night only!
2. `chmod 600 $CURRENT` should be done as soon as possible; if you are really afraid for the security of the file, do it before creating the tarball (as shown in my sample.)
3. Fix the `find` by adding a `+` in front of the `$ROTATE` number. This is something that gets me each time, so don't feel bad. Actually, if you use `+` it has the mean of *older or equal*, and if you use '-', the test is inverted (so `-mtime +7` is more or less equivalent to `! -mtime -7` — probably within 1 day in between which is not unlikely to match one side or the other.) With a plain number as you used (`-mtime 1`), it will delete files that were modified on that particular day. If that script does not run for 3 days, then those 3 files won't ever get deleted.
4. It is easier to use the `-delete` <s>so you do not have to think about the quotations you missed in your sample code (i.e. `-exec rm "{}" \;`) in case the filename includes special characters</s>.
5. I suggest you add a `-name` because you have a simple way to know whether the file in question is a backup. This is just for security. If you never ever put any other file in that directory (like a copy of a backup you want to keep for a longer period of time) then you do not need it.
6. Adding the `-e` option in the hash bang (`#!/bin/sh -e`) is a good idea so the script stops on the very first error. At times scripts run, generate errors, and you never see them.

Comment: FYI, `-exec rm {} \;` is perfectly safe as far as whitespace and special characters go.  It won't delete directories, but that's not called for in this case.